# Which Compiz plugins can I safely disable?

Tags: unity, 11.10, compiz, plugins

On 11.10, which Compiz plugins are enabled by default? I.e. I should leave them enabled for some particular reason.

I've imported my Compiz settings from my previous install and so I can't tell. I'd like to disable all unnecessary plugins because I've noticed the potential for interference or performance issues.

I don't think I can trust the CCSM feature "Reset to defaults" because when I use it I need to run `unity --reset` afterwards in order for my desktop to work again (implying that the default values it resets to are not the values that Ubuntu/Unity requires).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete all the Compiz configuration files on your Home Folder, so that Compiz will recreate them using the defualt values. Go to your home folder and delete then the following folders and files:

```
~/.cache/compizconfig-1
~/.compiz-1
~/.config/compiz-1
~/.gconf/apps/compiz-1
~/.gconf/apps/compizconfig-1
```

If you log out and log in again you should have just the default plugins enabled.

Comment: Since these are all user specific I ended up just creating a new user and used it to see which plugins are enabled by default, thanks!

Comment: That's a good idea. Glad you could solve your problem. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the part of the question regarding which plugins you can safely disable, I disabled all of them and didn't have any problems.  Then I went back and enabled a few I cared about like Desktop Wall which enables workspaces.

I did notice that a few plugins reenabled themselves automatically after I disabled them (possibly because of some of the other plugins I had reenabled manually):

- Window Decoration
- Move Window
- Resize Window

It might also be worth mentioning that the machine I did this on is running Ubuntu 10.10.